# Does powershell have a "netonly" equivalent?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I want to open AD from a different domain. Earlier i used this to do so:

```
runas /netonly /user:xxxx\xxxx "mmc dsa.msc /domain=xxxx"
```

Which worked fine but i wanted to make it into a GUI to make it faster so in powershell ISE i did this:

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential xxxx\$Account, $securePassword
Start-Process  mmc "dsa.msc /domain=xxxx"  -Credential $credential
```

I know the above bit of code works, if i try to use it to login to AD with a different user to a domain i am already logged then it works.

However when trying to use it to login to a different domain then i get the error. "The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship."
Same error i would get if i tried to run the first bit of code with out Netonly in CMD/Powershell.

How can i fix this? Does the "start-process" have anything like "runas" has /netonly that i can add to fix it?